# Angular2 Quickstart Tutorial Breaking Karma Tests - "Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'."

Tags: angular, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, ngmodel

I am following the official Angular "Hero" Quickstart Tutorial whilst trying to TDD it.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt1.html

As soon as I get to the step to replace:

```
<input value="{{hero.name}}" placeholder="name">
```

with

```
<input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name">
```

my Karma test runner throws the following error:

**Error: Template parse errors:
    Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("
                
                    name: 
                    ][(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name">
                 
        "): AppComponent@6:23
    Expected undefined to be defined.**

However, the application works as expected and I see no errors in the console. (And I'm fairly confident I followed the tutorial correctly, can't see any typos etc)

My app.components.ts looks like:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export class Hero {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
            <h1>{{title}}</h1>
            <h2>{{hero.name}} details!</h2>
            <div><label>id: </label>{{hero.id}}</div>
            <div>
                <label>name: </label>
                <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name">
            </div>
    `
})

export class AppComponent {
    title = 'Tour of Heroes';
    hero: Hero = {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Windstorm'
    };
}
```

My app.module looks like:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule],
  declarations: [ AppComponent],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Karma works fine as soon as I remove ngModel from the template, and as I said before the actual app is behaving as expected. I can't seem to find any information relating to my problem after extensive googling :(

My karma.config is the standard quickstart one:

```
// #docregion
module.exports = function(config) {

  var appBase    = 'app/';       // transpiled app JS and map files
  var appSrcBase = 'app/';       // app source TS files
  var appAssets  = 'base/app/'; // component assets fetched by Angular's compiler

  var testBase    = 'testing/';       // transpiled test JS and map files
  var testSrcBase = 'testing/';       // test source TS files

  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'), // click "Debug" in browser to see it
      require('karma-htmlfile-reporter') // crashing w/ strange socket error
    ],

    customLaunchers: {
      // From the CLI. Not used here but interesting
      // chrome setup for travis CI using chromium
      Chrome_travis_ci: {
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox']
      }
    },
    files: [
      // System.js for module loading
      'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',

      // Polyfills
      'node_modules/core-js/client/shim.js',
      'node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',

      // zone.js
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/sync-test.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/fake-async-test.js',

      // RxJs
      { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },

      // Paths loaded via module imports:
      // Angular itself
      { pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },

      { pattern: 'systemjs.config.js', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: 'systemjs.config.extras.js', included: false, watched: false },
      'karma-test-shim.js',

      // transpiled application & spec code paths loaded via module imports
      { pattern: appBase + '**/*.js', included: false, watched: true },
      { pattern: testBase + '**/*.js', included: false, watched: true },


      // Asset (HTML & CSS) paths loaded via Angular's component compiler
      // (these paths need to be rewritten, see proxies section)
      { pattern: appBase + '**/*.html', included: false, watched: true },
      { pattern: appBase + '**/*.css', included: false, watched: true },

      // Paths for debugging with source maps in dev tools
      { pattern: appSrcBase + '**/*.ts', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: appBase + '**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: testSrcBase + '**/*.ts', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: testBase + '**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false }
    ],

    // Proxied base paths for loading assets
    proxies: {
      // required for component assets fetched by Angular's compiler
      "/app/": appAssets
    },

    exclude: [],
    preprocessors: {},
    // disabled HtmlReporter; suddenly crashing w/ strange socket error
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],//'html'],

    // HtmlReporter configuration
    htmlReporter: {
      // Open this file to see results in browser
      outputFile: '_test-output/tests.html',

      // Optional
      pageTitle: 'Unit Tests',
      subPageTitle: __dirname
    },

    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  })
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

When configuring the test using the `TestBed`, it's like configuring an `@NgModule` from scratch for the testing environment. So when adding `AppComponent` to the `declarations`, and the `AppComponent` needs forms directives, you need to import the `FormsModule` into to the testbed configuration, just you do in the `AppModule`

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  imports: [ FormsModule ]
})
```