# Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. test .spec.ts

Tags: angular, angular2-testing

I haev been linked to another ticket.  This error ONLY occurs in test and I have imported the FormsModule per linked message.   I am using Angular 2.2.1.

ngModel not defined in 'ng test' I have imported FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule to no effect.   I have been researching this for 24 hours and I am no closer.  Most are related to upgrade,  I wiped and restarted with same issue,  testing template is pretty bare when created using ng generate.

I used angular cli to build my app (and rebuild it...)  and I have added forms import as it appears important.

Here is my simple template,  Note that it was not a form but a div and it makes not difference.   'ng serve' looks reasonable so the code is theoretically correct.

Here is my form...

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for='line1'>Address 1</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Line 1" id='line1' [(ngModel)]='address.line1' required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 control-label" for='line2'>Address 2</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="line2" placeholder="Line 2" [(ngModel)]='address.line2'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 control-label" for='Suburb'>Suburb</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="suburb" placeholder="Suburb" [(ngModel)]='address.suburb'>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="State" placeholder="State" [(ngModel)]='address.state'>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="postcode" placeholder="Postcode" [(ngModel)]='address.postcode'>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

here is my test spec,  I added CommonModule and ReactiveFormsModule and FormsBuilder after much research,  no joy.

```
    /* tslint:disable:no-unused-variable */

import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';


import { AddressComponent } from './address.component';
import { Address } from './address';

describe('Component: Address', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AddressComponent],
      imports: [CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
      providers: [FormBuilder]
    });
  });

  it('should create an instance', () => {
    let component = new AddressComponent();
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should handle address', () => {
    expect(true).toBeTruthy();
  });

});
```

This is my component.  Pretty simple...

```
import { Input, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Address } from './address';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-address',
  templateUrl: './address.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./address.component.css'],
})

export class AddressComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() address: Address;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Error I get is:

```
"): AddressComponent@4:78
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("iv class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="line2" placeholder="Line 2" [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]='address.line2'>
```

Comment: I am nit using rc5  I am using a freshly built app using angular cli.  It works with ng serve.   Testing issue only

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40373099/angular2-quickstart-tutorial-breaking-karma-tests-cant-bind-to-ngmodel-sin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the `FormsModule` as well

```
imports: [CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule],
```